# Can environments be easily wrapped with AUCTeX?

Tags: latex, auctex, replace, wrapping, wrap-region

I want to quickly wrap certain environments my cursor is within with text.

In my specific situation, I want to wrap the `frame` environment with the text

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
\makeatother
```

and

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
\makeatother
```

Here's a MWE to illustrate my situation:

```
 1  \documentclass[handout]{beamer}
 2  
 3  \begin{document}
 4  
 5  \begin{frame}
 6  
 7    \frametitle{Foo}
 8  
 9    \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
10      Foo bar.
11    \end{block}
12  
13    \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
14      Foo bar.
15    \end{block}
16  
17  \end{frame}
18  
19  \makeatletter
20  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
21  \makeatother
22  \begin{frame}
23  
24    \frametitle{Bar}
25  
26    \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
27      Foo \uncover<+->{bar.}
28    \end{block}
29  
30    \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
31      Spam \uncover<+->{eggs.}
32    \end{block}
33  
34  \end{frame}
35  \makeatletter
36  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
37  \makeatother
38  
39  \end{document}
```

If my cursor is anywhere between lines `5` and `17`, then issuing my desired command would produce:

```
 1  \documentclass[handout]{beamer}
 2  
 3  \begin{document}
 4  
 5  \makeatletter
 6  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
 7  \makeatother
 8  \begin{frame}
 9  
10    \frametitle{Foo}
11  
12    \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
13      Foo bar.
14    \end{block}
15  
16    \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
17      Foo bar.
18    \end{block}
19  
20  \end{frame}
21  \makeatletter
22  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
23  \makeatother
24  
25  \makeatletter
26  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
27  \makeatother
28  \begin{frame}
29  
30    \frametitle{Bar}
31  
32    \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
33      Foo \uncover<+->{bar.}
34    \end{block}
35  
36    \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
37      Spam \uncover<+->{eggs.}
38    \end{block}
39  
40  \end{frame}
41  \makeatletter
42  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
43  \makeatother
44  
45  \end{document}
```

Ideally, this command would toggle the wrapping, so with the cursor anywhere between lines `19` and `37` in the original file would produce:

```
 1  \documentclass[handout]{beamer}
 2  
 3  \begin{document}
 4  
 5  \begin{frame}
 6  
 7    \frametitle{Foo}
 8  
 9    \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
10      Foo bar.
11    \end{block}
12  
13    \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
14      Foo bar.
15    \end{block}
16  
17  \end{frame}
18  
19  \begin{frame}
20  
21    \frametitle{Bar}
22  
23    \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
24      Foo \uncover<+->{bar.}
25    \end{block}
26  
27    \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
28      Spam \uncover<+->{eggs.}
29    \end{block}
30  
31  \end{frame}
32  
33  \end{document}
```

Is this doable with the tools provided by AUCTeX?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new environment which wraps the `frame` environment with the code you want, so something like this in your preamble should work:

```tex
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Frame}[1][]{%
  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}%
  \begin{frame}[environment=Frame,#1]%
}{%
  \end{frame}%
  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}%
}
\makeatother
```

and then use the `Frame` environment instead of `frame`.

If you want to insert the code into your file, you have to write a function which can look like this:

```lisp
(defun my/LaTeX-beamer-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((p (point-marker))
        (s (make-marker))
        (e (make-marker)))
    ;; Get us into frame-env top-level:
    (while (not (string= (LaTeX-current-environment) "frame"))
      (LaTeX-find-matching-begin))
    ;; Now find the matching begin of "frame"
    (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
    (if (save-excursion
          (and (search-backward "\\makeatletter"
                                (line-beginning-position -5) t)
               (setq s (point))
               (search-forward "\\makeatother"
                               (line-beginning-position 5) t)
               (setq e (point))))
        (delete-region s e)
      (insert "\n"
              "\\makeatletter"
              "\n"
              "\\gdef\\beamer@currentmode{beamer}"
              "\n"
              "\\makeatother"
              "\n"))
    (goto-char p)
    ;; Get us into frame-env top-level:
    (while (not (string= (LaTeX-current-environment) "frame"))
      (LaTeX-find-matching-end))
    ;; Now find the matching end of "frame"
    (LaTeX-find-matching-end)
    (if (save-excursion
          (and (search-forward "\\makeatletter"
                               (line-end-position 5) t)
               (setq s (match-beginning 0))
               (search-forward "\\makeatother"
                               (line-end-position 4) t)
               (setq e (point))))
        (delete-region s e)
      (insert "\n"
              "\\makeatletter"
              "\n"
              "\\gdef\\beamer@currentmode{handout}"
              "\n"
              "\\makeatother"
              "\n"))
    (goto-char p)
    (set-marker p nil)
    (set-marker s nil)
    (set-marker e nil)))
```

In your file, do <kbd>M-x my/LaTeX-beamer-toggle RET</kbd> and see if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `TeX`.  But I can answer the ***"wrap a BODY TEXT with a PREAMBLE and POSTAMBLE"*** part.

1. Copy the below snippet to an empty `*scratch*` buffer, and do `M-x eval-buffer RET`

```lisp
(require 'tempo)
(setq tempo-interactive t)
(tempo-define-template "wrap-1"
               '("
\\makeatletter
\\gdef\\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
\\makeatother
"
                         n>
             r
             n>
             "
\\makeatletter
\\gdef\\beamer@currentmode{handout}
\\makeatother
" > %))
```

2. Mark a region of text, and do `M-x tempo-template-wrap-1 RET`.  Your text will be wrapped.

For example I started with this text

```
body
```

and did `M-x tempo-template-wrap-1 RET` when the above body text was active.  I got this

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
\makeatother

body

\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
\makeatother
```

You can read more about `tempo` library here [David's Elisp hacks](http://www.lysator.liu.se/%7Edavidk/elisp/) or here [EmacsWiki: Tempo Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TempoMode).

Or

You can read the `info` manual online at [Info manual for `tempo` library](http://www.lysator.liu.se/%7Edavidk/elisp/tempo.info), or download it, and read it right in your `Emacs` with `C-u C-h i temp.info RET` (`C-u M-x info RET temp.info RET`)

Or

If `tempo` is too old school for you, I am sure there are `yasnippet` recipes for what you want to achieve.  Keywords to search for are *"template"*, *"snippet"* etc

Comment: if you think that moving my paragraph is fragile, then you can add `% begin wrap` to the beginning of your preamble, and `% end wrap` to the end of postable, and use `C-r % begin wrap` and `C-s % end wrap` to do kill the preamble + postamble part.   The answer above uses ***big motion commands*** and ***keyboard macro***, and don't forget the mode-specific `menu bar` commands.

Answer (score 0):

## This answers the unwrap part

### Overview

```
| M-x package-initialize  <return>        | package-initialize        |
| C-x C-x C-f test.tex  <return>          | find-file                 |
| M-x display-line-numbers-mode  <return> | display-line-numbers-mode |
| M-g M-g 27  <return>                    | goto-line                 |
| C-2  C-c .                              | LaTeX-mark-environment    |
| C-u C-x r s a                           | copy-to-register  ?a      |
| C-<up>                                  | backward-paragraph        |
| C-SPC                                   | set-mark-command          |
| C-<down>                                | forward-paragraph         |
| C-w                                     | kill-region               |
| C-x r i a                               | insert-register   ?a      |
```

[image: Menu Bar for LaTeX]

### Detailed Answer

1. Copy the below snippet to `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  
  \frametitle{Foo}
  
  \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}
  
  \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}
  
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
  
  \frametitle{Bar}
  
  \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
    Foo \uncover<+->{bar.}
  \end{block}
  
  \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
    Spam \uncover<+->{eggs.}
  \end{block}
  
\end{frame}
\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

2. `emacs -Q`
3. `M-x package-initialize`
4. `C-x b *scratch*`.  Copy the below snippet and do `M-x eval-buffer RET`.

```lisp
(defalias 'unwrap
   (kmacro "C-u C-x r s a C-<up> C-SPC C-<down> C-w C-x r i a"))
```

4. `C-x C-f test.tex RET`.
5. `M-x display-line-numbers-mode`
6. `M-g M-g 27`
7. `C-2 C-c .`
8. `M-x unwrap RET`
9. Profit

Comment: If you think that moving my paragraph is fragile, then you can add `% begin wrap` to the beginning of your `preamble`, and `% end wrap` to the end of postamble, and use search motion commands---`C-r % begin wrap` and `C-s % end wrap`---to kill the *bare* `preamble + postamble` part. The answer above uses ***big motion commands*** *(the keybinding of these motion commands are standard across all modes)*, ***keyboard macro***, and don't forget the ***mode-specific menu bar commands***.  If you are serious about `Emacs` these are the parts you need to  focus on.